# jQuery is adding it's own session attribute in IE8 anchor tags?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I just got done migrating from MooTools to jQuery. When viewing the site in IE8 browser mode (which is fine in Firefox, Chrome, and IE9+, I noticed my anchors were no longer sending ajax calls.

I did some digging and noticed a strange attribute appended to the anchor tags:

```
<A id=button_overview class=btn_overview onclick="overview(); return false;" href="" jQuery17103184397447030644="11"></A>
<A id=button_profile class=btn_profile onclick=" getuserinfo(99, 'profile'); return false;" href="" jQuery17103184397447030644="12"></A>
<A id=button_reports class=btn_reports onclick=" reports(); return false;" href="" jQuery17103184397447030644="17"></A>
```

It is the word jQuery followed by a 20-digit number that differs upon page refresh, kind of like a session key. This key seems to be assigning values to itself based on the position of the specific anchor. As you can see in the snippet above, the particular hand-picked anchors I added here for reference are assigned 11, 12, and 17 for the attribute "jQuery17103184397447030644", which of course will change on refresh.

I am trying to get the ajax working again and don't even know yet if this is the issue, but it seems to be something obvious that's standing out I should look at.

When I view the actual requests when I click these anchors when capturing network request/responses, the request body seems to be blank, but the response does return the generic json data expected upon every request, just not the json data for the specific command sent because an actual command was never in fact sent.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not positive what those attributes are for, but rest assured that they don't actually affect your code. jQuery works just fine in IE. We need to see your code to find the issue, most likely it is an extra comma, unclosed quote, or invalid markup that gets automatically fixed by other browsers.

Comment: That attribute looks like the `expando` property jQuery adds when `data()` is called on an element. I don't think it's related to the problem you're experiencing. Try setting `href="#"` on your `<a>` elements instead of the empty string, there's a slight possibility IE8 doesn't like that.

Comment: wow, really? element storage via element attributes in IE? surely not, not even in jquery...

Comment: @Dimitar, the key to the jQuery data cache is actually persisted in an expando property, not an HTML attribute, but I suspect, as Beetroot does, that the questioner's DOM inspector renders these properties as attributes in its markup view.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will find that's the way jQuery stores data in the DOM with statements of the general form `$(selector).data('name',value);`. If I'm right, then such statement(s) must exist in your code or maybe in a plugin, and it seems that IE8's View Source decides to display such attributes in HTML xxx="..." form.

Again if I'm right, then the presence of these attributes should be evidence of the jQuery working properly; something else is preventing the ajax from working.

Comment: Double-checked this, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4TyL/1/) and inspect the anchor with the IE8-modus-developer-tools to see it in action.

Comment: Actually, you guys are correct. The addition of these attributes must be for compatibility reasons and are not the source of the error. In fact, most links do in fact work. Only the "Messages" link didn't work and it was because it is not receiving the proper ajax response. The response is returning a 304 not modified at the moment, which is putting it in jQuery's error() function rather than success(). I'm trying to figure out why it's not modified even when I echo something unique and exit the php script.

Comment: @Arion FWIW, [this update to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4TyL/2/), displays the jQuery data attribute in an alert box. It certainly shows in Opera and IE9 and I expect it will do so in all browsers.

Comment: Correction - Jeroen's fiddle - sorry @Jeroen, -respect-.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot thanks for that last fiddle, it really put it into perspective and goes along with the suspicion that Frédéric has about IE8 rendering this property in the DOM inspector when it shouldn't. Seems clear. Thanks everyone for the help on this.